# Batch-compressing/archiving files within subcategories (files have to be in the root)

Tags: parameters, batch-file, zip, archive, subdirectory

I've been searching for a while now to archive a LOT of photographs in different directories into seperate zip-archives. With no luck so far. How come? I have some specific requests;

The directory-structure:

YEAR => Category (12 directories, the same for each year) => Each Category has it's own events => Each event has it's own pictures. For example:

2013\

--------Category1\

--------Category2\

--------Category3\

-----------------------Subcategory1\

--------Category4\

--------Category5\

--------Category6\

-----------------------Subcategory1\

-----------------------Subcategory2\

------------------------------------------Photograph1.jpg

------------------------------------------Photograph2.jpg

--------Category7\

and so on...

Year: 7 directories
Subcategories in each year-folder: 12
Sub-subcategory in each Subcategory folder: 100-200
Photographs inside all folders: 70GB, not sure how many files exactly.

## My question

I would like to create individual zip-archives for each subcategory. Here's the catch:
The zip archives must fulfil to 2 requests:

1) The photographs have to be placed in the root of the zip-archive. When you open up a zip-archive, the first thing you have to see are photographs. No (sub)directories.

2) If possible, the zip-archives have to be limited to a filesize of 150mb each. So even if a subcategory contains 200mb of photographs, the script/parameters have to set limits to the filesize. Not just 'splitting up' a 200mb zip-archive, but really make 2 seperate zip-archives. One being 150mb in size, the other 50mb.

Would this be possible to do? There are a lot of ways to archive files by scripts and I did try a few, but none of them seem to work the way I want it to work ;-)

So... the zip-archives have to be put in the same sub-category besides the photographs, can't be any bigger then 150mb each and have to understand what files have to be zipped (the content of sub-categories within a sub-category within the year-category).

Thanks! :)

Comment: Interesting job. And they can't be any bigger then 150 MiB each?

Comment: Well, here's the thing. I have about 70GB of photographs, which need to be imported into a photo-gallery system on my website. The system has a couple restrictions. One of those is: You can import zip-archives (including photographs), but my server has some restrictions when it comes to uploading files. I already managed to increase the size from 2MB to 150MB, but the system crashes on zip-archives bigger than that :)

Comment: in WinRar you can specify the archive size on the command line :)

Comment: I tried WinRAR, but another restriction the system has: the uploaded/imported zip-archives can only contain photographs in the root. No directories in the root. And that's what WinRAR does. Put the pictures within a directory in the root.

Comment: WinRar makes folders with the `x` command: `rar x myarchive`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to think with me :) Though I did manage to create seperate .zip-archives from the content within seperate folders, there are still 2 issues. 1) the split-up at 150MB makes the series of .zip-archives kind of buggy. Where archive_part01.zip should be 150MB in size after archiving with size-limit, it actually shows it's only 8MB (while there are 150MB of photographs inside). Also, the splitting-progress splits parts of photographs in half. So 30% is spread over part01/02/03 (so tos speak), and the other half over the other parts. It should be 100%. Does that make sense? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  Save this with a `.vbs` extension.  I haven't tested it thoroughly, but I think it should work.  For each directory that contains files, it will zip those files to an archive within the same containing directory.

Oh, and welcome to SO!  Since you are new, you might want to check [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716).

```
' archive_limit.vbs
' usage: cscript archive_limit.vbs (directory, optional)
' If directory is not supplied, traverse subdirectories of current

on error resume next
if WSH.arguments.count = 0 then
    dir = left(WSH.ScriptFullName,(Len(WSH.ScriptFullName))-(len(WSH.ScriptName)))
else
    dir = WSH.arguments(0)
    if not Right(dir, 1) = "\" then
        dir = dir & "\"
    end if
end if

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set shl = createobject("shell.application")

EnumFolders(fso.GetFolder(dir))

WSH.Quit 0

Sub EnumFolders(fFolder)
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    zipnum = 1
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        zipfile = fFolder.Path & "\archive" & zipnum & ".zip"

        If fso.FileExists(zipfile) Then
            projected = fso.GetFile(zipfile).Size + objFile.Size
            if projected >= 157286400 Then
                zipnum = zipnum + 1
                zipfile = fFolder.Path & "\archive" & zipnum & ".zip"
            End If
        End If

        if not fso.FileExists(zipfile) Then
            set zip = fso.createtextfile(zipfile)
            zip.write "PK" & chr(5) & chr(6) & string(18, chr(0))
            zip.close
        End If

        If Not LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "zip" Then
            ' uncomment the following line to log progress to the console
            ' WSH.Echo "Zipping " & fFolder.Path & "\" & objFile.name & " to " & zipfile
            zipitems = shl.namespace(zipfile).items.count
            shl.namespace(zipfile).copyhere(fFolder.Path & "\" & objFile.name)
            do until shl.namespace(zipfile).items.count > zipitems
                WSH.Sleep 100
            loop
        End If

    Next

    For Each Subfolder in fFolder.SubFolders
        EnumFolders(Subfolder)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: rojo, You are a life-safer! :) Thank you so much so far!

Here are some things I noticed though:
- Every time a jpg-file has been progressed/read/zipped, the vbs shows a message.

Comment: <continuing>


Windows Script Host

Zipping <path>

I have to press OK (every time) to get rid of it.

Also, the script doesn't accept filenames with special characters (it crashes). Let's say the letter: ç

It also crashes giving me this error:
Line: 44
Character: 13
Error: Object required: 'shl.namespace(...)'
Code: 800A01A8
Source: Runtime error Microsoft VBScript

Thank you so much for you help so far! :)

(and I meant to spell life-saver) ;-)

Comment: For the pausing, instead of double-clicking the script to launch it, launch it using cscript from a cmd prompt.  Either that or remove the wsh.echo line.  I'm not sure what to recommend about filenames with extended Unicode characters.  Maybe make sure the vbs file is saved as Unicode or with the appropriate code page?  That might be worth posting as a separate question.

Comment: I removed the Echo line. That did the trick :) To test the script, I created a couple of test-directories with a few images. One directory now has 155MB of photographs. I removed all photographs with special characters (except for underscores, those seem to work at folders with only 1 photograph in it). Still it crashes at a certain point with the same error as before: Line: 44 | Character: 13 | Error: Object required: 'shl.namespace(...)' | Code: 800A01A8 | Source: Runtime error Microsoft VBScript

Comment: ... Or maybe try enclosing the file path and name variables in triple quotes.  I'm not at a computer right now so I can't test my theory.  I'll try it tomorrow if you need me to.

Comment: @Joy - Try this.  At the top of the script add the following line: `on error resume next`

Comment: This is kind of tricky to explain: double-clicking the vbs-file or just running it with command prompt; both have their issues. Both ways stop running when archive1.zip has reached 148MB (you can see the size increase during the progress). No second archive is being created with the rest of the photographs. Command prompt automatically shuts down at this point. Not everytime, but once every 2 or 3 tries, it shows a new warning saying the compressed directory is empty (or something like that). Could  you please (or tomorrow) explain how I should add the triple quotes? Is that ''' or  """? Tnx!

Comment: @Joy - I just realized I had a logic error in my script where the zip file rotates when full.  I fixed it.  Also, I'm curious to see whether the `on error resume next` fixes the Unicode problem.  Try the update please, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That did the trick! Really appreciate the help :) Never thought all these options were able to be put together into one script :) Running the .vbs-file still crashes now and then, but the command-prompt seem to work correctly. Thanks for making some time :)

Comment: Just has to be mentioned that this seems to work only if zip folders are enabled. Besides this, the solution is good.